# Reset SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that first inserts some data into a temp table and then inserts a row into another table. I am calling Scope_Identity() after the second insert to pick up the newly inserted record Identity.

If the second insert does nothing due to a join, I want to check the Scope_Identity and raise an exception. But Scope_Identity is returning the last identity created from the temp table insert before the second insert.

Is there a way to reset SCOPE_IDENTITY before calling the second insert, or a better way to determine if the second insert didn't actually insert anything?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check `@@ROWCOUNT` *immediately* after the 2nd insert. If it is 0 then no rows were inserted.

```
INSERT INTO YourTable
SELECT ...

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN
RAISERROR('Nothing inserted',16,1)
RETURN
END
```

Answer (score 8):

[Martin Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4571914/) totally answers your question.
This is apparently the only page on the internet asking how to reset the Scope_Identity().
I believe this is vital for anyone working with T-SQL.
I am leaving this answer for anyone who came here (like me) looking for the identity that was inserted by the previous insert statement (and *not* the last randomly successful identity insert).
This is what I came up with:

```
SET @SomeID = (CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN SCOPE_IDENTITY() ELSE NULL END)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think other answers given may be more practical, but I did want to record my finding here in case it helps someone some day.  (This is in SQL Server 2005; not sure whether this behavior persists in newer versions.)

The basis of the trick is an exploitation of the following property (from Books Online's documentation of `@@IDENTITY`): "After an INSERT, SELECT INTO, or bulk copy statement is completed . . . If the statement did not affect any tables with identity columns, @@IDENTITY returns NULL."  Although I can't find it explicitly stated, it appears that this behavior applies to `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` as well.  So, we complete an `INSERT` statement that does not affect any tables with identity columns:

```
CREATE TABLE NoIdentity (notId BIT NOT NULL)

-- An insert that actually inserts sets SCOPE_IDENTITY():
INSERT INTO YourTable (name)
SELECT 'a'
WHERE 1 = 1 -- simulate a join that yields rows

SELECT @@identity, SCOPE_IDENTITY()
-- 14, 14 (or similar)

-- The problem: an insert that doesn't insert any rows leaves SCOPE_IDENTITY() alone.
INSERT INTO YourTable (name)
SELECT 'a'
WHERE 1 = 0 -- simulate a join that yields no rows

SELECT @@identity, SCOPE_IDENTITY()
-- Still 14, 14 . . . how do we know we didn't insert any rows?

-- Now for the trick:
INSERT INTO NoIdentity (notId)
SELECT 0
WHERE 1 = 0 -- we don't actually need to insert any rows for this to work

SELECT @@identity, SCOPE_IDENTITY()
-- NULL, NULL.  Magic!

INSERT INTO YourTable (name)
SELECT 'a'
WHERE 1 = 0 -- simulate a join that yields no rows

SELECT @@identity, SCOPE_IDENTITY()
-- Still NULL, NULL since we didn't insert anything.  But if we had, it would be non-NULL.
-- We can tell the difference!
```

So, for your case, it would seem that you could do

```
INSERT INTO NoIdentity (notId)
SELECT 0
WHERE 1 = 0
```

to reset `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` before performing your second `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

Having considered several alternatives, I find myself liking a riff on [@BenThul's answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8992683/200993):

```
DECLARE @result TABLE (id INT NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO YourTable (name)
OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO @result (id)
SELECT 'a'
WHERE 1 = 0 -- simulate a join result

SELECT CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM @result) = 1 THEN (SELECT TOP 1 id FROM @result)
    ELSE -1
END
```

As you can see from my final `SELECT CASE...`, in my situation I was trying to end up with a single `INT NOT NULL` that would help me understand whether a row was inserted (in which case I wanted its ID) or not.  (I would not recommend being in this situation in the first place, if possible!)  What you would do with `@result` depends on what you need to do.

I like that the relationship between the `INSERT` and `@result` is explicit and unlikely to be contaminated by other intervening operations I might not be thinking about.  I also like that `@result` naturally handles cases with more than one row inserted.

Answer (score 0):

[MikeTeeVee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17373952) which I found when combined with the answer from [Martin-Smith's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4571914) is very powerful.

Here is my merged use:

```
BEGIN TRY

INSERT INTO YourTable
SELECT ...

SELECT @SomeID = (CASE WHEN @@ROWCOUNT > 0 THEN SCOPE_IDENTITY() ELSE NULL END)

IF (@SomeID IS NULL)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Nothing inserted',16,1)
END

END TRY 

BEGIN CATCH
    /* Handle stuff here - In my case I had several inserts
       - some could not happen and I did not raise errors for them
       - Some had to make a Transaction to rollback 
    */
END CATCH
```