# How to use SCOPE_IDENTITY to retrieve the last ID that was inserted

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Suppose I have two table. First table's primary key is the foreign key for another table.

Table `Member` has its primary key as the foreign key in `Member_detail`.

So when I insert a row in `Member` table using a Stored Procedure, I need to get the primary key value to add to the `Member_detail` table.

One way I was using is :

```
SELECT Max(MemberID) 
FROM Member
```

Then passing this `Memberid` to my `Member_detail` table, but on the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6799738/primary-key-value-after-insertion-of-row-in-sql-server-2005), I read that the `Max` function is not recommended and that I should use `SCOPE_IDENTITY`, but I don't know how to use of it.

Can anyone give me some example?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY` returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope.

Given you have 2 tables:

```
Member: id int (primaryKey), name varchar

Member_Detail: id int (primaryKey), pk int (foreignKey), name varchar
```

You can do this:

```
DECLARE @MemberId int

INSERT INTO Member (name) VALUES ('hello');

SET @MemberId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO Member_Detail (pk, name) VALUES (@MemberId, 'hello again')
```

**MSDN Reference:**

### [SCOPE_IDENTITY (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger, function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

Comment: SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last identity values that are generated in any table in the current session. SCOPE_IDENTITY returns values inserted only within the current scope

Comment: my next question might be silly. but please dont mind. if there are two users and both are doing insertion at the same time then for the each user scope_identity value will be different after insertion? for both there will be different session ?

Comment: It returns the last IDENTITY value produced on a connection and by a statement in the same scope, regardless of the table that produced the value.
SCOPE_IDENTITY(), like @@IDENTITY, will return the last identity value created in the current session, but it will also limit it to your current scope as well. In other words, it will return the last identity value that you explicitly created, rather than any identity that was created by a trigger or a user defined function.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen "funny" behavior with scope_identity.  As a result, I like to use an output clause.  Here's an example:

```
declare @id table (i int)
insert into Member (name) values ('NightKnight')
output (MemberId) into @id

select * from @id
```

Comment: Be aware that if someone adds a trigger to the `Member` table, then the `OUTPUT` clause will give you an error: [The target table 'Member' of the DML statement cannot have any enabled triggers if the statement contains an OUTPUT clause without INTO clause](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13198476/12597)

Comment: @IanBoyd - that issue is specifically why I use an INTO clause in this answer.